# Alpine linux: readelf(missing). How to install readelf on Alpine Linux?

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux

When I'm trying to install `readelf` package on Apline3.5, I got this error message.

```
$ apk add --no-cache readelf
client readelf
fetch http://dl-    cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  readelf (missing):
    required by: world[readelf]
```

I want to solve this problem with only some command.
That's because, I would like to be able to do it with Dockerfile.
What should I do??

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use `binutils` packages for the same

```
$ apk add --update binutils
(1/2) Installing binutils-libs (2.28-r2)
(2/2) Installing binutils (2.28-r2)
Executing busybox-1.26.2-r5.trigger
OK: 13 MiB in 14 packages

$ readelf
Usage: readelf <option(s)> elf-file(s)
 Display information about the contents of ELF format files
 Options are:
  -a --all               Equivalent to: -h -l -S -s -r -d -V -A -I
  -h --file-header       Display the ELF file header
  -l --program-headers   Display the program headers
```